# Spring Web-Flux Configure Route Deserializer

Tags: kotlin, jackson, spring-webflux

All I want to do is apply the FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES rule for my jackson deserializer so that when mandatory primitive fields are missing an error is actually thrown.

I have tried just about every way to configure Jackson but none seem to actually be applied at run time because deserialization always succeeds and just puts in Kotlin default primitive values.

Here is the class I wish to deserialize

```
data class MyClass(
    val number : Int,
    val names: List<String>
)
```

The following JSON when sent to my route should fail when FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES is set to true but this never occurs.

```
{
    "names" : ["John", "Jim"]
}
```

I have tried using my application.yml file with

```
spring:
  application:
    name: my-app
  jackson:
    deserialization:
      FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES: true
```

And this does nothing.

I have also tried giving it a custom object mapper

```
@Configuration
class JacksonConfig {
    @Bean
    fun objectMapper(): ObjectMapper? {
        return ObjectMapper().enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES)
    }
}
```

Still nothing.

I am wondering if it has something to do specifically with web flux or using a RouterFunction. For clarity here is my router

```
@Bean
fun routes(
  handler : MyHandler
): RouterFunction<ServerResponse> {
  return router {
      ("/api/v1/" and (accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)))
         .nest {
             POST("route", handler::postData)
          }
```

and here is my handler

```
@Component
class MyHandler(
    private val service: MyService
) {

    override fun postData(request: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {

        val body = request.bodyToMono(MyClass::class.java).log()
        val result = body.flatMap {request ->
            service.doThings(request)
        }

        return result.flatMap {
            ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).bodyValue(
                "IT WORKED"
            )
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had a rouge `configureHttpMessageCodecs` method that I wasn't aware of that just kept forcing the default object mapper. Anyways this config class did the trick for me.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
class MyConfig:WebFluxConfigurer {
    @field:Autowired
    lateinit var jacksonObjectMapper : ObjectMapper


    override fun configureHttpMessageCodecs(configurer: ServerCodecConfigurer) {
        val defaultCodecs = configurer.defaultCodecs()
        jacksonObjectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES)
        defaultCodecs.jackson2JsonDecoder(Jackson2JsonDecoder(jacksonObjectMapper, MimeType.valueOf("application/json")))
        defaultCodecs.jackson2JsonEncoder(Jackson2JsonEncoder(jacksonObjectMapper, MimeType.valueOf("application/json")))
    }

}
```